# Get arguments passed by Smart Banner iOS from flutter web safari

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have implement a simple code to my flutter web app:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners
Now it shows a banner on top if app is installed or not.
If app is install it shows "Open" otherwise it shows "View" which takes to download.
Now the issue is as per the documents it says you can pass specific arguments if needed like this:

I want to know how do i check in flutter app if the app is opened from smart banner from safari and which app-argument was passed down on opening the app.
I am stuck on this issue for 3 days now.

Answer (score 1):

Use native [application(_:open:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application) method to get access to `app-argument` and [Write custom platform-specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to access it from Flutter or maybe use [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links) plugin.

Comment: Will https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links (Uni links) will give me the link which i clicked from Safari Smart Banner?
Because i think it uses the application(_:open:options:) method for both deep links and app links/universal links.